# MPMoviePlayerViewController Status bar not hiding

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, mpmovieplayercontroller, uistatusbar

hello i am working on a App which play video in an Application
and i have used following code -

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie=
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: myurl];
theMovie.moviePlayer.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
theMovie.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[theMovie.moviePlayer play];
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
```

but i want to remove this status bar from the Video controller please see the attach file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

ViewDidLoad Method:

```
    float delay = 0.1;

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC),  dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
```

ViewWillAppear method give this below Code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your view controller:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

or
 write this in appdelegate.m

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Or add the property Status bar is initially hidden in your plist file

[image]

Folks, in iOS 7+

please add this to your info.plist file, It will make the difference :)

UIStatusBarHidden UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance

[image]

I don't know if apply for your case, but in my case the status bar appears after I loaded a UIImagePickerController and change my default screen orientation.

I fix this situation add application.statusBarHidden = YES; inside appDelegate like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
// Detect if I need to hide the StatusBar (optional)
if (iNeedToHide == YES) {  
    application.statusBarHidden = YES;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

i hope it will help you

Comment: but i want status bar hidden only when video plays

Answer (score 0):

in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
application.statusBarHidden=YES;
}
```

or

use this code it will help you:

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}
```